# Python - pypdf2 extractText() not working

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to extract text and then editing finally , but the text is not getting extracted , it is showing the number of pages , header elements correctly , only the extractText() is not working.

-This is my code-

```
import PyPDF2 as o

#File Object

pdfFileObj=open('answkt.pdf','rb')

#Render Object

pdfReader=o.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

#no of pages

print(pdfReader.numPages)

#page Object

pageObj=pdfReader.getPage(0)

#extract text

print(pageObj.extractText())

#close

pdfFileObj.close()
```

Comment: Your PDF file may be non-searchable, i.e., the text therein is saved as an image.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel is right i tried your code its works for text based PDF file only if file is image or graphics or scanned copy its not work. Tried changing text base PDF try this https://idrh.ku.edu/sites/idrh.ku.edu/files/files/tutorials/pdf/Text-searchable.pdf

Comment: @JustinEzequiel can you suggest any other a way to handle pdfs ? It seems this code is working for text only files

Comment: Here's one example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reading-contents-of-pdf-using-ocr-optical-character-recognition/

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for this on youtube but I want to share the code to you!
Enjoy!

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
import io

def pdf2txt(inPDFfile, outTXTFile): 
    inFile = open(inPDFfile, 'rb')
    resMgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retData = io.StringIO()
    TxtConverter = TextConverter(resMgr, retData,laparams = LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resMgr, TxtConverter)
    
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(inFile): 
        interpreter.process_page(page)
        
    txt = retData.getvalue()
    with open(outTXTFile, 'w') as f: 
         f.write(txt)
   
inPDFfile = "Resume.pdf" # your file path
outTXTFile = "sample.txt" # what ever the name you want enjoy!
pdf2txt(inPDFfile, outTXTFile)
```